# Create discrete random variables to find the probability that both events A and B happen

Tags: statistics, sympy

I've been learning the sympy stats module by trying to solve some elementary problems in discrete probability.  I'm stuck on creating random variables from a joint distribution of two events.

Consider an experiment consisting of two consecutive die rolls.  The sample space is a set of tuples consisting of the value of the first die followed by the value of the second die: (1,1), (1,2), (1,3) ...

There are 36 possible outcomes in this sample space.

Now, say I want to calculate the probability that the value of the first die is even **and** the second die is 3.  There are three possible outcomes:(2,3), (4,3), (6,3) so the probability is 3/36 = 1/12.

I can't find a way to express a random variable for this sample space.  I could use Die or FiniteRV to create a random variable with 36 equally likely outcomes and then map the tuples to these outcomes but that seems like a lot of coding for an elementary problem like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I worded it poorly, I was trying to calculate the probability of intersections and unions of sets of random variables.  I don't think there is a way to do that directly in sympy stats; instead, I'll have rely on the relations:

P(A∩B) = P(A|B)*P(B)

P(A∪B) = P(A) + P(B) - P (A∩B)

```
 from sympy.stats import Die, P
 from sympy import Eq
 A=Die('A',6)
 B=Die('B',6)
 P(Eq(A%2,0),Eq(B,3))*P(Eq(B,3))
```

out: 1/12

Comment: Or just  P(Eq(A%2,0)) * P(Eq(B,3)) since the events are independent.

Comment: True for this trivial example.  Not true in general.

Comment: There is still the issue of creating bivariate or multivariate  distributions for discrete random variables.  As far as I can tell, sympy.stats does not support that.